# Nuxt issue with post

Tags: node.js, heroku, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I made some app that is making a request to a server and was working fine in development mode, but when I push it to Heroku it doesn't make any call to the server and in the console I see that is trying to request `localhost:3000/request`.

This is a Nuxt.js app and I am making the request with Axios.
I tried adding `cors()` but it didn't work. It is probably something about Nuxt.

```
axios.post('/request', data)...
```

Comment: What is your axios base URL? https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig The base URL should ideally be derived from the environment (e.g. env variable).

Comment: i dont have one, how to pass url to nuxt.config?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/134

Comment: yes that was the issue, i put BASE_URL in heroku config variables but now i get 404 error  https://damp-mesa-37152.herokuapp.com/jobs 404 (Not Found)... what should i put for  BASE_URL value?

Comment: put answer to answer section so i can make your response as answered

Comment: Is this the correct URL for your service? You must specify the first part of the URL as baseURL, Then, the actual request is added to this baseURL (e.g. `'/request'`)

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `baseURL` of axios. The base URL should ideally be derived from the environment (e.g. env variable). So, specify the axios in the Nuxt.JS config and axios should request the data from the correct URL.

Here is a snippet of the adapted Nuxt.JS config:

```
modules: [
  ['@nuxtjs/axios', {
    baseURL: 'https://<YOUR-BASE-DOMAIN>'
  }]
]
```

There is also an issue report on axios for nuxt: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/134